# NAT traversal with Java

Tags: java, traversal, nat

I want to connect to computers, each one of them behind a NAT router. I read that STUN only works with one computer behind a NAT router. Is that true? If so, how can I solve that double-NAT problem?

Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917385/nat-traversal-with-java/

Answer (score 3):

[UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) and [TCP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching)

Answer (score 1):

[TURN](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-behave-turn-16) is a set of extensions to STUN that *help* to solve the double-NAT problem. You still need a server in the cloud, and the clients need to register. Source for some free servers is [available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relay_NAT).

From the TURN internet draft:

> As described in [RFC5128] and
> [RFC4787], hole punching techniques
> will fail if both hosts are behind
> NATs that are not well-behaved.    For
> example, if both hosts are behind NATs
> that have a mapping    behavior of
> "address dependent mapping" or
> "address and port    dependent
> mapping", then hole punching
> techniques generally fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you dó not have a central server, you May consider using upnp if available to create a hole in the router. Azureus/vuze does this.