# Need suggestions for android socket programming

Tags: java, android, sockets, port

We are developing an android app that send and receives text messages via wifi.
We use TCP sockets for this communication (ip address and random port) but the problem is that if i dont allow these port numbers from my router's "port forwarding section", messages couldnt be sent.
Are there any way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Eh, you could always spin up a free EC2 server.

Comment: why not just pick a port, or some predictable algorithm that chooses ports and can be replicated on both sides?

Comment: even if we choose a port number and try to connect with it, we still need to make port forwarding from router.

Answer (score 0):

You could pick the ports randomly from within a selected range and forward that range in your router like this:

int port = (Math.abs(random.nextInt())) % 3000 + 1024;

This way I have generated a random number betwen 1024 and 2999. Or just pick a fixed port.

Comment: this is exactly what we did. the problem is that the router doenst allow to communicate unless we allow it to use that spesific port.

Comment: Then that would be an issue with your router I'd say. Since this is what I've used so far.

Comment: this is what i dont understand: when we try to send messages with our app, we need to allow that port from router.
when we try to download something with any torrent client using random ports, there is no problem.
both applications are p2p. how can i download files, but cant send/receive messages?

Comment: I could be mistaken but perhaps your p2p software uses known ports.

Answer (score 0):

If both clients are behind different restrictive firewalls, you should look into holepunching, where both clients open a connection with a third server, then the third server predicts the port opened on the NAT: [NAT traversal with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116403/nat-traversal-with-java), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917385/nat-traversal-with-java/. Note that this is typically needed for P2P applications (i.e., client to client) as you describe here. Yes, it's horribly complex and nasty :(

You might be better off storing the messages in the cloud with something like Amazon Cloud Services and using a push-based mechanism to notify the other party on message reception, perhaps using Long Polling HTTP.