# Java Socket: cannot communicate between two computers using Socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have made two programs using Java that can communicate using Socket and They work fine on my own PC. But when I try to do the same thing between two computers, It does not work, as if the computers cannot find each other or something else. (I get the IP Address of the computer that works as the server using *ipconfig* in CMD)

What ever is wrong here, is not about the code. I even turned off the firewalls on both computers, but I nothing changed. Can anyone help me out?

MyServer.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyServer {

    // Scanner Object
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Objects
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static Socket socket;
    static DataInputStream dIs;
    static DataOutputStream dOut;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            // Setting Up Message
            System.out.println("Server Waiting For Connections...");

            // Setup Server Socket
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6666);

            // Accept Client Connection Request
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            // Confirmation Message
            System.out.println("Client Connected.");

            // Data Input Stream
            dIs = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            // Data Output Stream
            dOut = new  DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            String Input = "";

            while (!Input.equalsIgnoreCase("close Connection")) {
                // Read Client Message
                Input = dIs.readUTF();
                System.out.print("\nClient: " + Input);

                if (!Input.equalsIgnoreCase("close Connection")) {
                    // Send Server-Side Response
                    System.out.print("\nResponse: ");
                    dOut.writeUTF(scan.nextLine());
                    dOut.flush();
                } else {
                    dOut.writeUTF("Connection Closed.");
                    dOut.flush();
                }
            }                       
            closeConnections();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Error Message
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
            closeConnections();
        }           
    }

    public static void closeConnections() {
        try {
            // Close Connection         
            dIs.close();
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Connection Closed.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Could Not Close Connections.");
        }
    }
}
```

MyClient.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyClient {

    // Scanner Object
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Objects
    static Socket socket;
    static DataInputStream dIs;
    static DataOutputStream dOut;   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // Setup Connection Socket For Client
            socket = new Socket("localhost",6666);

            // Data Input Stream
            dIs = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            // Data Output Stream
            dOut = new  DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            String Input = "";

            while (!Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Close Connection")) {
                // Send Client-Side Message     
                System.out.print("\n- Client Message: ");
                dOut.writeUTF(scan.nextLine());
                dOut.flush();

                // Read Server Message
                Input = dIs.readUTF();
                System.out.print("\nServer Response: " + Input);                
            }
            closeConnections();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Error Message
            System.out.println(ex);
            closeConnections();
        }       
    }   

    public static void closeConnections() {
        try {
            // Close Connection
            dIs.close();
            dOut.close();
            socket.close(); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Could Not Close Connections.");
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: They're not visible to each other because of [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116403/nat-traversal-with-java) for some explanations and possible solutions.

Comment: Are both computers on the same local network?

Comment: Yes they are @MauricePerry

Comment: @ Kayaman in "This PC" I can see the other computer from "Network Locations" section! they are visible to each other I think.

Comment: @keivanIpchi could it be a routing problem?

Comment: What do you get if you try to 'telnet' to the server. Is a connection refused ?

Comment: @Maurice Perry I don't think so. In that case, computers couldn't find each other in "Network Location" section, right?

Comment: Connecting To 192.168.x.x...  Could not open connection to the host, on port 13531: Connect failed @ jr593

Comment: From the first PC, I can see the second one through "Network Location". But I can't see the first one from the second PC. Can that be the problem?

Comment: 13531? I thought it was 6666

Comment: This is the sample on the internet. I tried it with 6666 but did not work. @ Maurice Perry